# Logic of repository pattern laravel

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I am learning to use the Laravel framework.

I came across the repositories, said in several sites be a good practice of development.

I found some packages that help implement this practice in Laravel, but missed some features, but I think I'm failing to understand very well the logic and its benefits.

Considering studying that part, I created a package that shows how to think is this implementation, but I still have many questions.

https://github.com/guilhermegonzaga/repository

Ex:

Scopes and relations should be transferred to the repository or kept in the model?

How to implement the type functions `"increment(), decrement()"` in the repository? or is it correct to call them on the controller?

```
$model = $repository->find($id);
$model->increment();
```

Thank you

Comment: What do you want achieve with your `increment/decrement` methods?

Comment: Please check "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )"

Comment: eg where a product is displayed, increase the view column in my model. This creates coupling of my model with the controller, and the purpose of the repository is to decouple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the relationships set in the model:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

When you are talking to the model from within the repo you can then pull the relationship information if needed. The increment and decrement should be done in the repository.

Check out this quick article to get a better understating of what you are trying to achieve using the repository pattern:

http://culttt.com/2014/09/08/benefits-using-repositories/

Comment: Thank you. Scopes should also be transferred to the repository?

Comment: I have not done much with scopes but at a quick glance it seems like something you would want to avoid doing on the model level as a rule you should try and decouple your modal from the repository as well as your decoupling your service layer from the repository.